# Visual Studio Online CI Nunit references not resolved during build

Tags: c#, build, visual-studio-2013, nunit, hosted

I have been trying to get my solution to build in a CI configuration using Visual Studio Online and the hosted build controller.

I have created a folder in the root of my workspace with the required NUnit binaries as per [these guidelines](http://www.visualstudio.com/get-started/hosted-build-controller-vs#supplemental_binaries).

I have also referred to these previous questions where users had issues trying to accomplish the same thing:

- [Visual Studio Online CI Nunit Tests not found during build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20027235/visual-studio-online-ci-nunit-tests-not-found-during-build)
- [What else is needed to get the Hosted Build Controller to run my NUnit tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22461317/what-else-is-needed-to-get-the-hosted-build-controller-to-run-my-nunit-tests)

I have the "NUnit Test adapter for VS2012 and VS2013" package installed in all of my test projects.

The error messages in my build log are like this:

> Tracking_works_when.cs (35): The type or namespace name 'TestAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

The type 'TestAttribute' is one of several missing ones, including 'Test', 'TestFixture' and 'TestFixtureAttribute'.

There is also the following warning:

> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets (1605): Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "nunit.framework, Version=2.6.3.13283, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=96d09a1eb7f44a77, processorArchitecture=MSIL". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors.

The same warning is repeated for "nunit.core.interfaces" and "nunit.core".

**Question:**

What am I missing?  Why are my NUnit binaries not being identified within the hosted build environment and my tests run automatically?